# Possible race condition with netcat and heredoc

Tags: bash, netcat, heredoc

I am doing the level 24 of Bandit in OverTheWire and I have a problem when trying to solve it.
In this exercise you need to connect with the localhost over the port 30002 and introduce a password and a pin of 4 digits.

My bash script is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc localhost 30002 << Input
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0000
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0001
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0002
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0003
...
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 9998
UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 9999
Input
```

The problem is that when I read the output there have been 7175 retries instead of 9999.
Anyone knows what could be happening?

Comment: Replace `nc localhost 30002` with `wc -l` and see what it considers the line count to be

Answer (score 0):

You close your nc at the end of your last send line, but don't wait for the answer. I don't know `nc` in detail, maybe there are option for a delayed closing.

Anyway, this should work (sleeptime may vary):

```
( cat << Input
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0000
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0001
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0002
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 0003
    ...
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 9998
    UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ 9999
Input
sleep 2
) | nc localhost 30002
```